# Значение пословицы "клад дается человеку досужему"

Tags: этимология

Пословица гласит: *клад дается человеку досужему*.
Каким должен быть человек, чтобы ему дался клад? Знающим, умеющим или щедрым?

Comment: Что-то в пунктуации подправить надо бы (: -) и хоть два слова сказать об источнике: чья пословица, какого времени.

Comment: Из текста так получается, что досужим должен быть, а не знающим, умеющим или щедрым.

Comment: Виноват, исправлюсь

Comment: смотрел в интернете значение слова досужий, наше, что написал.

Answer (score 1):

"Я много раз слыхал, что **без досужего человека клад никому в руку не дается**; как не успеешь сказать: «Аминь, аминь, рассыпься!» – так и ступай искать его в другом месте"( М. Н. Загоскин. Юрий Милославский, или русские в 1612 году).

**Существуют поверья, что клад кладется  с зароком** и дается тому только, кто исполнит зарок, **именно поэтому найти клад может человек знающий**, как отвести зарок, какие сказать заклинания и т.д.

**Из современного словаря:**

ДОСУЖИЙ,  Разг. 1. Не занятый работой, делом; праздный. Д-ие сплетницы, зеваки. 2. Вызванный праздностью, бездельем; пустой. Д-ие домыслы, выдумки, фантазии, измышления. Д-ие разговоры, речи, сплетни. Д-ее воображение.

**Из словаря XVIII века:**

ДОСУ́ЖИЙ  Расторопный, проворный, а также умелый, искусный в каком-л. деле. Важна хозяйка, домовита, Досужа, ласкова, умна. Ко всему готов, угоден, способен, досуж.

Так какой же он на самом деле: искусный, сведущий, знающий, умеющий или праздный бездельник?     Казалось бы, досуг от досягать/достигать. **Почему же тогда так изменилось значение слова?**

**Из словаря Черных:**

Слово "досуг" известно в русском языке с XIV века, досужество – это умение, ловкость, способность, дарование,  но уже с XV века у слова "досуг" появляется значение "свободное время".

Как предполагают этимологи, развитие значения шло **по схеме:** досуг (успешность, достижение результата, удача) – возможность располагать временем по окончании труда – отдых.

Answer (score 1):

> Пословица гласит: -клад дается человеку досужему. **Каким должен быть
>   человек, чтобы ему дался клад?**

.

***— Способным к делу, расторопным, искусным.***

===

Из *"Словаря церковно-славянского и русского языка"* середины 19-го века:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

В традиции русского народа,  многих других народов, щедрость, хлебосольство и пр. подобные качества. 
Дается благо тому, кто поделится с другими. Досож- щедрый, досужий -щедрый человек. 
Устроить досуг может человек щедрый, досу(о)жий. 
Для обозначения умелого, знающего, могущего есть русские (роськие) слова с корнем зна.
Хотелось бы напомнить, что в современном талышском языке, как в языковом заповеднике, сохранились слова и выражения древней составляющей русского языка - роського.

Comment: безымянный  минус подобен "шептуну" в компании. Поделитесь, что не понравилось?